# What dependencies does JEDI Visual Component Library need for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, jvcl, delphi-12-athens

I'm trying to install JEDI Visual Component Library from GetIt in Delphi 12.

[image: JEDI Visual Component Library from Delphi GetIt]

It successfully installed the "JEDI Code Library", but then failed on the "JEDI Visual Component Library".

It says:

> No Delphi/BCB/BDS/RAD-Studio versions was found that has the required dependencies installed. Please install the dependencies first.

> Failed to compile JVCL installer

These errors appear in a popup Terminal CMD window:

[image: Failed to compile JVCL installer]

What are the dependencies that are missing? Do I need to install something else first?

Comment: Is it a trial version? Trial and CE do not include the command line compiler. https://support.embarcadero.com/article/44692

Comment: It's a licensed Delphi 12.

Comment: Doesn't JVCL require JCL installed??

Comment: Do you have the Delphi 12 Patch 1 installed? https://blogs.embarcadero.com/getit-update-additional-rad-studio-12-getit-packages-are-now-available/#120_Patch_1_is_Also_Available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you have the [Delphi 12 Inline Patch 1 installed](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/getit-update-additional-rad-studio-12-getit-packages-are-now-available/#120_Patch_1_is_Also_Available) because the original Delphi 12 has issues with GetIt.

And then on the new Delphi 12 Inline Patch 1, you'll see there are two separate GetIt packages for JEDI. There's a "JEDI Code Library" and a "JEDI Visual Component Library". They're now separate instead of being combined into one GetIt package.

[image: Delphi GetIt Package Manager (JEDI)]

First, install "JEDI Code Library" and restart your IDE afterwards. Then install "JEDI Visual Component Library" and restart your IDE again. If you do it in this order with the new Patch 1 installed, then it will work.

---

"JEDI Visual Component Library" only has one dependency and that is "JEDI Code Library". I think the install failed in your instance because the IDE was never restarted after "JEDI Code Library" was installed. It could also be due to the GetIt bugs in the original Delphi 12 version. But I just did it successfully without any issues in the new Delphi 12 Inline Patch 1.